# Ctrl-[ not working in Windows 8 or XP running in Parallels virtual machine

Tags: windows-8, gvim

I'd like to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> work, i.e., have it exit insert mode, in VsVim in Visual Studio and in gVim both on my Windows XP and Windows 8 Pro virtual machines under Parallels 9 running on OS X Lion. I really don't know why that key sequence does not seem to work under both Windows OSs.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> works in gVim, but I don't care for that key sequence as an alternative (especially since it has other semantics in Visual Studio). I have no `vimrc` set up on Windows and thus no key mappings and indeed running `:map` and that keychord (which I can't type here because of the angle brackets?) reports "no mappings found". I've interacted with the author of VsVim (who is very helpful) to no avail thus far as seen [here](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/1214). I think it is something on my system since it happens in gVim too. The key sequence works great for me in Emacs where I have my viper config set to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> to viper escape on both OS X and Windows. So the physical keyboard works fine. Lots of googling hasn't yielded a solution yet.

Any ideas on how to see why this is happening, or, even better, a solution for this problem? For instance, if something is consuming the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> chord system wide (or application wide?), how do I find what it is? I am really stumped on this one as I am not a Windows expert or a Parallels expert (though, as I say, I've googled this quite a bit with an eye toward Windows and Parallels).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

Esc (the escape key) exits modes such as 'Insert' mode and 'Visual' mode and causes gVim to go back into 'Normal' mode. Ctrl-[ does this as well, both Esc and Ctrl-[ perform the same function in gVim.

Unfortunately, as the OP mentioned, pressing Ctrl-[ in gVim in a Parallels Virtual Machine running Windows doesn't make gVim exit back to 'Normal' mode like it's supposed to. But pressing Esc fortunately does make gVim exit back to 'Normal' mode.

### Solution

You can fix this issue by creating a shortcut from Ctrl-[ to Esc.

Steps to create the necessary shortcut:

1. Open Parallels Desktop.
2. Go to: Parallels Desktop menu -> Preferences -> Shortcuts tab ->
   [Your Virtual Machine] (Under the "Virtual Machines" heading).
3. Click the '+' button to add a shortcut.
4. In the textbox in the "From" section, press the **[** key.
5. Click the "^ Ctrl" button in the "From" section.
6. Click the textbox in the "To" section, then press the **esc** key.
   This should make the word "Esc" appear in the textbox.
7. Click the "OK" button.

Comment: Jay, thank you!! Really appreciate you taking the time to post this. It works.